# $and query in mongodb is not resturning results

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

I'm new with using mongodb and NoSql in general.

This is an example of the json code that I'm trying to query

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c351ae3d85ef0793dacc041"),
    "Year" : 2008,
    "State" : "NY",
    "Producer Type" : "Commercial Cogen",
    "Energy Source" : "All Sources",
    "CO2
  (Metric Tons)" : "590,598",
    "SO2
  (Metric Tons)" : "1,094",
    "NOx
  (Metric Tons)" : "2,390"

}
```

I'm trying to return ALL results (so multiple results) that show the state as NY and energy source as coal.

```
db.emissions.find({ $and:[{"state":"NY"}, {"energy source": "coal"}]})
```

It is not returning any results.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

```
 db.emissions.find("state":"NY","energy source":"coal")
```

and

```
db.emissions.find({ "State":"NY", "Energy Source": "Coal"})
```

are not working correctly either unfortunately

But simply sorting out the case sensitive letters in the `$and` query worked! Thanks!

Comment: Wow thanks both!! @saravana, it seems like it did have to do with case sensitivity! Even "Coal" was with capital C.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried simply

```
{ field1: <value>, field2: <value> ... }

db.emissions.find( "state":"NY", "energy source": "coal")
```

Careful I think "Energy Source" <> "energy source"

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Field names are case sensitive

Please try

```
db.emissions.find({ $and:[{"State":"NY"}, {"Energy Source": "coal"}]})
```

or simply

```
db.emissions.find({ "State":"NY", "Energy Source": "coal"})
```